# wxpython: wxgrid without vertical scrollbar

Tags: wxpython

is posible remove the automatic horizontal scrollbar in a wxgrid?

Answer (score 5):

show horizontal, hide vertical scroll bar:

```
grid_object.ShowScrollbars(wx.SHOW_SB_DEFAULT,wx.SHOW_SB_NEVER)
```

hide horizontal and vertical scroll bar:

```
grid_object.ShowScrollbars(wx.SHOW_SB_NEVER,wx.SHOW_SB_NEVER)
```

Comment: When you activate the vertical scrollbar it 'eats in' on the width of the column next to it. Is there a way to really set it next to the column without decreasing the column width of the outer right column?

Comment: Note, on wxPython 2.8.11.0 I get: "'Grid' object has no attribute 'ShowScrollbars'"; but in the C++ API, the function has apparently been there since 2011: [wxWidgets Discussion Forum • View topic - wxGrid does not display scrollbars](https://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=31693)

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, no. As I found in the mailing archives from Robin Dunn, wx developer and wxPython creator/maintainer:

> Although you can deactivate the
>   scrollbars by using the wx.Window and
>   wx.ScrolledWindow methods dealing with
>   scrolling, the Grid class resets
>   itself at various points and they just
>   come back.  So there really isn't any
>   way to disable the scrollbars, other
>   than making the window large enough
>   that they are not needed.

[reference](http://wxpython-users.1045709.n5.nabble.com/Disable-Scrollbar-in-wxGrid-td2369653.html)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with horizontal scrollbars hiding the lowest row of my grid, and the grid not expanding with its panel. I found some info on the issue here:

https://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=44663&sid=99086632d76e75110e93f5c806f36d3b

What worked for me, however, was simply initializing the grid with a very large vertical size, e.g.

```
grd.Grid.__init__(self, parent, -1, name=str(myid), size=wx.Size(100,1000))
```